# merge different schema in graphql

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

schema.js

```
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

module.exports = buildSchema(`
type Booking {
    _id: ID!
    event: Event!
    user: User!
}

type Event {
    _id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    price: Float!
    creator: User
}

type User {
    _id: ID!
    email: String!
    password: String
    createdEvents: [Event!]
}
type RootQuery {
    events: [Event!]!
    users: [User!]!
    bookings: [Booking!]!
}

schema {
    query: RootQuery
}

`);
```

index.js

```
app.use(
'/graphql',
graphqlHTTP({
    schema: graphQlSchema,
    rootValue: graphQlResolvers,
    graphiql: true
})
);
```

I am just trying to learn graphql and it's my first time so I am a little bit confused above query is working fine but what I want 3 different files for booking, user, event and merge them in a single file name index.js and after that import in the main index.js which is above one. This is the first time I am learning graphql. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Type definitions (SDL) merging](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/merge-typedefs) of `graphql-tools` package to merge your type definition files.

> This tools merged GraphQL type definitions and schema. It aims to merge all possible types, interfaces, enums and unions, without conflicts.

E.g.

`types/booking.js`:

```js
module.exports = `
type Booking {
    _id: ID!
    event: Event!
    user: User!
}
`;
```

`types/user.js`:

```js
module.exports = `
type User {
    _id: ID!
    email: String!
    password: String
    createdEvents: [Event!]
}
`;
```

`types/event.js`:

```js
module.exports = `
type Event {
    _id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
    price: Float!
    creator: User
}
`;
```

`types/index.js`:

```js
const { mergeTypeDefs } = require('@graphql-tools/merge');
const bookingType = require('./booking');
const userType = require('./user');
const eventType = require('./event');

const rootTypes = `
type RootQuery {
    events: [Event!]!
    users: [User!]!
    bookings: [Booking!]!
}

schema {
    query: RootQuery
}
`;

const types = [bookingType, userType, eventType, rootTypes];

module.exports = mergeTypeDefs(types);
```

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema, print } = require('graphql');
const typeDefs = require('./types');

const app = express();
const port = 4000;
const schema = buildSchema(print(typeDefs));
console.log(print(typeDefs));

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
  }),
);

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server started at port:', port));
```

Server logs:

```
type Booking {
  _id: ID!
  event: Event!
  user: User!
}

type User {
  _id: ID!
  email: String!
  password: String
  createdEvents: [Event!]
}

type Event {
  _id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  price: Float!
  creator: User
}

type RootQuery {
  events: [Event!]!
  users: [User!]!
  bookings: [Booking!]!
}

schema {
  query: RootQuery
}

Server started at port: 4000
```